# Were there any other monsters in Doctor Who which were a play on words?

Tags: doctor-who

The Daleks were originally the Kaleds. Notably, Dalek is Kaled spelt backwards.

This is just a simple play on words. Were there any other monsters in the long running Dr.Who series that were a play on words, perhaps of the preceding kind, but not neccessarily so?

Comment: That's not what "play on words" means. It would be if "Dalek" or a homophone/graph had a different meaning that was related in some way. This is just a retconned anagram.

Comment: @OrangeDog  +1 on your comment for "retconned".

Comment: Please don't rollback my edit, the correct spelling _is_ Doctor in this context and you have not tagged the question appropriately, this needs the work tag and that is it.

Comment: In what sense is that a retcon?

Comment: it's a retcon because it wasn't mentioned  until Tom Baker, and directly contradicts the first Dalek story where it was stated that they were originally called the Dals before they mutated.

Comment: "Dalek" spelled backwards is "Kelad", not "Kaled".

Answer (score 1):

K9 is a play on canine. (Yes, I count him as a monster.  "Monsters" in Doctor Who doesn't always mean evil or enemy, just non-human and fictional. A robot counts as a monster, even when he's a friend of the Doctor)

The only other one I can think of is the Drashigs from [Carnival Of Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival_of_Monsters).  Writer Robert Holmes named them thus as a deliberate pun in the expectation that the special effects department would make them out of dishrags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there have been lots. Not just monsters though - the show is full of puns, anagrams and wordplay.

**Examples of characters:**

- **K9** - a robot dog, and a pun on *canine*.
- **Androgum** - a race obsessed with eating, and an *anagram* of 'gourmand'.
- **Mister Saxon** - an alias of The Master, and an anagram of 'Master No. Six' (Simm was the sixth incarnation of The Master)

**Other anagrams:**

- **Torchwood** is an anagram of *Doctor Who*.
- **Osterhagen Key** - featured in the episode 'The Stolen Earth'. 'Osterhagen' is an anagram of "earth's gone".

**Episodes with 'pun' titles:**

- **'42'** - episode with 'real-time' action, a pun on the real-time show '24' and also a reference to classic Who script-editor Douglas Adams who used the number '42' in his Hitchhikers Guide series.
- **'Dinosaurs on a Spaceship'** - a pun on the movie 'Snakes On A Plane'.
- **'Spyfall'** - a pun on the Bond movie title 'Skyfall'.
- **'The Woman Who Fell To Earth'** - a pun on the 1963 sci-fi novel 'The Man Who Fell to Earth'.

Answer (score 0):

*The Face of Evil* gives us two in-universe puns:

> The Sevateem (Survey Team) and the Tesh (Technicians)

Answer (score -1):

Not quite what you're asked, but the Big Finish drama Spare Parts - which deals with the origin of the Cybermen - had the Mondas society generally refer to people as "something-man" - "Doctorman", "Sisterman", etc.